# cross domain jquery ajax request in IE with xDomain Request not working

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

I have used the following code to make a cross domain jquery ajax request in IE with    xDomain Request.

```
var xdr;  
 var URL=parentDomain+"/chat/getmessagesservlet";

 if (jQuery.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {  

   // Use Microsoft XDR
   var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    xdr.open("POST", URL + '?to='+chatboxtitle+'&yourName='+myName+'&chatBoxIndex='+tabIncr);
    xdr.onload = function () {
   var dom  = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
   dom.async = false;
  JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText); 
   if (JSON == null || typeof (JSON) == 'undefined') {
    JSON = $.parseJSON(data.firstChild.textContent);   
   }

    processData(JSON); // internal function
   }; 

   xdr.onerror = function() {
     _result = false;    
    };
   xdr.send();

    } else {
    $.ajax({ 
      type: 'POST', 
       url: URL,   
          processData: true,
          data: {'to':chatboxtitle,'yourName':myName,'chatBoxIndex':tabIncr}, 
           dataType: "json",
          async: false,
          success: function (data) {
            processData(data);   
           }
});

}'
```

Also i set header on server side as follows:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");   
response.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods"," GET, POST");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
```

But In IE8 & IE9  it is not working . ResponseText return null or is empty . 
i have seen that using jQuery

```
.ajaxTransport( dataType, handler(options, originalOptions, jqXHR)
```

or

```
.ajaxPrefilter( [dataTypes ], handler(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) )
```

it is possible to make cross domain request.But i don't know how to use this in my  code.
what are the values to be passed in options & originalOptions paramter?
please give me guidance to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
xdr.onprogress = function () { }; //Needed to save IE9 from melting.
```